# Error applying facet_wrap() in geom_sf() incomplete polygon in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a shapefile with 7 regions.
I have an excel file with data about reptiles in these 7 regions.
I merged this shapefile with excel.

Using ggplot I tried to generate facet_wrap() from `nome_popular`, however the rest of the polygon parts were omitted in each facet created.

My tentative code

shapefile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I1m9lBX69zjsdGBg2zfpii5H4VFYE1_0/view?usp=sharing

excel:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eKQWWCAalehTTrUuqUlMPQnSTEZxF--g/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118442515534677263769&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
# load data.frame
serpentes <- read_excel("E:/22-serpentes_cg/R/serpentes_cg_finall.xlsx")

# filer data.frame
total_especies <- serpentes %>%
  rename(regiao_cg = REGIAO_CG) %>%
  group_by(
    especie, nome_popular,
    regiao_cg
  ) %>%
  summarise(Total_esp = sum(quant))

# load shapefile
regiao <- sf::st_read("E:/22-serpentes_cg/geo/regioes_urbanas.shp") %>%
  rename(regiao_cg = REGIAO_CG)

# join shapefile and excel
total_especies_shp <- dplyr::left_join(regiao, total_especies, by = "regiao_cg")

# map facet_warp
p_total_especies_shp <- ggplot(
  na.omit(total_especies_shp),
  aes(fill = factor(Total_esp))
) +
  geom_sf() +
  scale_fill_brewer(
    palette = "Spectral", na.value = "grey", direction = -1,
    "Total de\nSepertens Regatadas"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~nome_popular)

p_total_especies_shp
```

output incomplete

[image]

OBS EDIT

I tried @stefan's answer which partly worked, but generated a facet called "NA" bad.

new code:

```
p_total_especies_shp <- ggplot(total_especies_shp)+
  geom_sf(data=regiao)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=factor(Total_esp)))+
  scale_fill_brewer(
    palette = "Spectral", na.value = "grey", direction = -1,
    "Total de\nSepertens Regatadas")+
  
  facet_wrap(~nome_popular)

p_total_especies_shp
```

[image]

Comment: would you mind creating a better MCVE without the need for downloading anything from google drive? We all hope that SO will be around for a long time and the way this data is required makes it quite likely not reproducible any more sooner rather than later. This makes the question maybe useful to you, but not to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on @stefan answer, if you want to get rid of the NA panel, you need to provide the data in the second geom with the na.omit, leaving the ggplot call empty:

```
p_total_especies_shp <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = regiao) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(Total_esp)), data = na.omit(total_especies_shp)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(
      palette = "Spectral", na.value = "grey", direction = -1,
      "Total de\nSepertens Regatadas"
    ) +
    facet_wrap(~nome_popular, drop = TRUE)
  
  p_total_especies_shp
```

Which gives the result you want:
[image]

Comment: Is the NA not showing in the caption?

Comment: Yes, this way there is no NA in the map nor the legend, but empty polygons are showed in the map

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that with faceting the data is splitted in groups and only the polygons contained in the splitted data will show up.

If you want all regions to be shown in each facet then one option would be to add a base map via second `geom_sf` layer. In your case `+ geom_sf(regiao) + geom_sf()` should do the job.

As an example I make use of the default example from `?geom_sf`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
base <- nc
nc$facet <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), size = nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(data = base) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand this `nc$facet` command. how am I going to apply it in my reality.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. This line of code is not important. Was only meant to add a variable to the example data which I could use for facettting. Simply add `geom_sf(regiao)` to your code and stick with your faceting variable.

Comment: I tried to adapt your code to my situation. I noticed that the solution you presented doesn't have the `na.omit` as I put it. This way your code even works, but it created a facet called "NA" bad.